# Launching Python has encounterd a. Unable to get project for the run

Tags: python, python-3.x, aptana

Launching Python has encounterd a problem. Unable to get project for the run

It would let me put the word problem in the title.

The title is the exact message i get when i try to run/debug a file in Aptana 3.

I have always been able to run Python in Eclipse without problems. Does anyone know what causes this error?

For testing purposes i just created a new Pydev project with only 1 file in it.

Comment: Have you recently changed your interpreter settings? Try creating a new run configuration.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, please help me if you resolve this issue please.

Comment: I created a new "Python Run" in the setting of "Debug Configurations" for testing at yesterday, and forgot to remove it, so when I make an new Python file and runing with it using this new-run at default.
After I remove this python-run, everything is OK again.
So, I advice you to check your "Python Run" in the setting of "Debug Configurations", for making sure which python-run you are using now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with Aptana and just solved it. In my case I had configured another interpreter (IronPython) for running another script. When I got back to a previous script I got the same error message as you "Unable to get project for the run" because it was trying to run it with IronPython instead of Python.

I would therefore recommand the following:

1) Check your interpreter configuration.
-> Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter Python

If you have no interpreter there try autoconfig. If it doesn't work you will have to browse it yourself by clicking New (then it should be somewhere like C:\Python27\python.exe)

2) If you have an interpreter, it means that Aptana is trying to run your script with another interpreter. In that case right click on your script file in Aptana -> Run as -> Python run.

That worked for me.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks @Serge.  This fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run -> Run configurations -> Python run 
delete "New configuration" 
then it must work

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you create a **New configuration** for run a program.
go to **Run** > **run configuration** > **python run**

**select** "New configuration"

press on **delete** icon

and again **Run** the program .

this is worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Below action solved my problem.

Go to Run > run configuration > python run
Delete all the configurations below python run - it may not be a great option if you have any custom configuration settings.